# outer join linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to Linq to object and have a question about the `from` clause when used in two contexts:

1) to perform a cross join like the query bellow

```
  var q1 = from person in people
      from job in jobs
      select new {person, job}
```

2) to perform an outer join

```
  var q2 = from person in people
     join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
     from subpet in gj
     select new { OwnerName = person.FirstName, PetName = subpet.Name };
```

does the second from clause acts as a cross join or is it evaluated depending on the context? because
q1 will produce people.Count * jobs.Count element
but q2 will produce only people.Count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MS documentation, to make the second query the left outer join you should use the DefaultIfEmpty method as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb311040.aspx). The from clause always evaluates the same way: it returns each element in the sequence, will it be either predefined source, or a context variable.

**EDIT:** I'll try to explain from the start. At first you inner join (group join, to be specific) the people and the pets. Then you select from the resulting collection (actually the person-pets set) to the new anonymous object, getting the person name (from the gj set element) and the subpet name (for each of the pets in the gj set element). I think the second from does not do crossjoin because it selects from gj, and each person is already a part of gj set element. If you call the gj.DefaultIfEmpty() method in the second from clause, then the person without any pets (with empty pets collection inside the gj set element) will be added to the resulting set. You can read the following articles to understand it better:

- [GroupJoin method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534297.aspx)
- [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: for the query 'q1' the second `from` act as cross join between elements from people and elements from jobs, what's the case for the second query?

Comment: In my opinion, the `from` clause does not act as a cross join, but the select does. The `from` is only the means to do a cross join, because it provides the elements from the sequences. In the second example you produce the person-pet inner join to gj, and use the second `from` to select every element from the resulting set, nothing more, nothing less. To perform a left outer join you should replace the right value (from gj set) with a null for a person without a pet.

Comment: is that mean the `from` acts as a foreach loop and the second `from` an inner foreach inside the first one ?

Comment: I've updated my post and tried to explain the matter in a greater detail.

Comment: I cannot say why it is as it is, but I think that the compiler "knows"  that person is in the gj and does not translate that part into a crossjoin. I am not sure about this, but you can try decompile your code using any of the available .net decompilers and check it out. I think you'll find an answer when you'll look at the translated code.

Answer (score 0):

[`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) is generally used to correlate the elements of two sequences based on a matching key, so it is *typically* an inner join, but it does depend on what you define as a match, e.g. the following would produce a cross join:

```
List<int> A = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> B = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var c = (from a in A join b in B on 1 equals 1 select new { a, b }).ToList();
```

Comment: my question was about the `from` clause (the seconde one in the queries) not `join`, is it acting the same way for the the two queries (q1 and q2), or it produces cross join for the first one and an outer join for the seconde one?

Answer (score 0):

From is evaluated based on the context. If it wasn't, you wouldn't be able to use context variables like `gj`. But if you don't use that context, like in your first query, it behaves the same as a cross join.

You're saying the second query gives you an unexpected number of elements. Maybe you shouldn't focus on that, but on what elements are you getting and how does that differ from what you are expecting.

Comment: for the query 'q1' the second `from` act as cross join between elements from people and elements from jobs, what's the case for the second query?