# How to Filter Child Collection from each Parent Entity in the Parent Collection using Linq

Tags: linq, dbcontext

Using linq (EF dbcontext), I need a statement to filter the child entity collection for each parent entity in a strongly-typed, IEnumerable parent entity collection.

Example:
I have 4 hotels and each hotel has several room reservations throughout the year. 
However in the month of June, one (1) hotel does not have any reservations (reservation.Count=0) but the other three hotels have several reservations each.

Problem:
Attempt #1: `IEnumerable(hotel) HotelList = (from hotels in context.Hotels select hotels).ToList();`

Without a 'where' clause (filter) I get IEnumerable(hotel) HotelList collection of 4 hotels and IEnumerable(reservation) ReservationList collection of all the reservations in the database (I only want those in June)!

Attempt #2: `IEnumerable(reservation) ReservationList = (from reservations in context.Reservations where reservations.reservation_date_month == 'June' select reservations).ToList();`

If I filter reservation dates for only June, my hotel count is 3 not 4.

Question:
I need a linq statement that selects the 'parent' hotel collection and filters the 'child' reservation collection to include only the reservations in the month of June (remembering that one hotel has no reservations in June).

Expected Result:
The result should be the parent IEnumerable(hotel) HotelList collection (includes all 4 hotels entities) and the child IEnumerable(reservation) ReservationList collection that lists all reservations in June for each hotel entity except that one (1) hotel will have reservations.Count = 0 (i.e. no reservation entities).

Thanks - jd

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the `join` by your own:

```
from h in context.Hotels
join r in context_Reservations on r.hotel_id equals h.id
where reservations.reservation_date_month == 'June'
group new { h, r } by h into g
select new { Hotel g.Key, Reservations = g.Select(i => i.r).ToList() }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you have a structure where each reservation references the hotel it belongs to. Then, what you need is an **outer join** which links hotels to its reservation. Using an outer join instead of an inner join ensures that hotels with no matching reservations will be in the output, too. For more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137655/outer-join-linq).